# How to programmatically click a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I have a `TextBlock` `MouseDown` event:

```cs
tb.MouseDown += (s, e) => {
  ToSp.Children.Add(CreateTbAlp((s as TextBlock).Text, ToSp));
  CheckAnswer();
};
```

And in Unit Test I need to test it. I tried:

```cs
TextBlockAutomationPeer peer = new TextBlockAutomationPeer(tb);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

But in this case, I get the error

> System.NullReferenceException

same with this one

```cs
typeof (TextBlock)
  .GetMethod("MouseDown", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
  .Invoke(tb, new object[0]);
```

Is there any other way to click `TextBlock` programmatically ?

Comment: The whole purpose of WPF and the MVVM design pattern is to not have to do ungodly hacks of this kind.  Are you sure that this is how you want to build your app and this is how you want to go about testing it?

Comment: Or, to ask the same questions using different words: why have you decided to use the Microsoft UI Automation API?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBlock.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TextBlock.MouseDown));
```

Comment: didn't work : The event 'UIElement.MouseDown' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=